# Is magento2 remove="true" global like in mage1?

Tags: magento2, layout, blocks, xml

In magento1 the remove tag was global and once a block was removed it could never be added back in:

```
<remove name="catalog.compare.sidebar" />
```

Is the same true in magento2?

```
<referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.sidebar" remove="true" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't a simple yes or no answer unfortunately. From looking at the remove section in the [dev docs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html#fedg_layout_xml-instruc_ex_ref) it sounds like you can easily remove and 'unremove' blocks with `remove="true"` and `remove="false"`.

Now I say this isn't a simple answer as the functionality doesn't seem to work, or not always as expected anyway. Quite a few people have noted that if a block has been removed in a parent theme, then setting `remove="false"` does nothing - taken from [this Github issue](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/1931).

So until that issue has been resolved I would say yes it is the same as Magento one, once a block has been removed it cannot be added back.